# Aren't laws actually just logical axioms?

Tags: criminal-law, jurisprudence

For example, don't kill people. If everyone killed each other then laws wouldn't exist.
Same with theft or any other basic law.

Or, pay taxes. Without taxes Government would collapse and law wouldn't exist.

Aren't the important laws just unavoidable generic physical limitations and exist regardless of being codified?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://philosophy.stackexchange.com

Comment: If *nobody* pays taxes then sure, the government doesn't survive.  The purpose of the law is to specify what happens when *most* pay taxes but a few do not.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that different places have different laws hint a "no" answer?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch the accepted answer in [Do philosophy of law questions belong here?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/61/26060) say that this type of question is on-topic

Comment: Tax-funded governments are not the only one who can, and do, make laws.

Comment: Mathematics can apply or exclude a variety of axioms depending on the system. The use of different axioms and how changing them affects the resulting structure is a significant area of study. Having different axioms doesn't mean they're not the basis of a logical system. @Greendrake

Comment: You assume that without laws against it the human race would be so busy killing each other that it would become extinct? Despite this not happening in other species with no concept of law.

Comment: Some laws are illogical: it's legal to drive on the motorway in germany even with near empty gas. But it is a misdemeanor to run out of gas on the same road. It's illegal to wear high heels on the Akropolis - but everybody is responsible for their own injuries on the akropolis anyway. In Spain, it is illegal to build sandcastles and nobody knows why. And in Australia it is not allowed to object to a marriage *even if one is asked to*!

Comment: @Nij If only law was an exact science...

Comment: I think this is on topic, as pointed out in the Meta post linked in the comment by @Ooker above. I am voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No

Laws are not "logical axioms" in the technical sense. In classic (Greek) mathematics, "axioms" were ideas thought to be so self-evidently true that no proof of them was needed or offered. In modern (19th Century and later) mathematics, axioms are the statement that serve as the basis of a given logical/mathematical formal deductive system. They are **assumed** to be true, and all other statements in the system are assessed by whether they can be proved by proper deduction from the axioms or not. Note that different systems have different sets of axioms, and an axiom in one system may be a derived theorem in another, and false in a third. This technical sense of "axiom" can really only be applied to statements in a logical or mathematical formal deductive system.

In a less technical sense, an "axiom" may be taken to be a fundemental truth, often thought of as self-evident. For example, the opening of the [US Declaration of Independence](https://www.archives.gov/founding-docs/declaration-transcript):

> We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness.--That to secure these rights, Governments are instituted among Men, deriving their just powers from the consent of the governed,

was declaring those statements to be axioms in this informal sense. But note that all of them were propositions hotly debated at the time, and far from universally agreed to since.

The question mentions laws against killing and theft, and laws imposinmg taxes. It asks:

> Aren't the important laws just unavoidable generic physical limitations and exist regardless of being codified?

They are not. While it is true that a society in which people frequently killed each other with no control whatsoever would not be a stable or long lasting one, many societies have existed in which killing was tolerated and even encouraged in particular circumstances. Much the same could be said of theft. And there have been stable societies with no formal governments, and others that had governments but did not have anything like modern taxation. I would venture to say that the is no law whatsoever that has existed in all known human societies in an invariable form or content. For any law, even "fundamental laws", one can find a society which had very different laws on that subject.

As just one example, I point to saga-period Iceland, roughly during the period from 900-1260 CE. The legal system is described in some detail in Chapter 10 of  *Legal Systems Very Different From Ours* by David Friedman, *et al*. There was no king or central executive authority. There was a detailed system of laws, and a hierarchical systm of courts with four basic levels:  The local thing court or *Vorþing*; the quarter-thing for disputes between members of different things within the same quarter; the four quarter courts of the Althing (*alþingi*) or national assembly; and above the quarter courts, after the reforms credited to Njal, was the fifth court. There was a complex system of rules for what killings were acceptable. Some killings could be done freely, some required the payment of a *wergeld* or manprice, others resulted in a judgement of lesser outlawry (which was for a,limited period if the subject was able to leave Iceland) or full outlawry (which was for life).  There wer detailed laws governing marriages ans sexual relations, and many other aspects of life. There were no taxes in the modern sense, although local thingmen did pay an annual sum for the support of the local *goði* and his *goðorð* (congregation). The amount was negotiated, and a man could change to a different *goði* if the amount was too high. (The *goði* were apparently originally builders of temples to traditional deities, who served as their priests. But their fundamental importance in the legal system remained after Iceland became Christian in the year 1000, although their priestly functions ceased.)

Thius is just one example of a system where there was a highly developed system oi law, but many of the fundamental laws the question assumes were absent oir very different.

Answer (score 1):

> Aren't laws actually just logical axioms?

No. That perspective is valid in fields such as physics and mathematics when referring to a small set of core propositions about systematically observed facts (examples are the laws of Newton, of Thermodynamics, etc.) on which a usually extensive body of knowledge is premised (examples: *naive* vs. *Zermelo-Fraenkel* set theory), but not in a context of legal systems.

The [Black's Law Dictionary](http://heimatundrecht.de/sites/default/files/dokumente/Black%27sLaw4th.pdf) defines *axiom* as "*[a] self-evident truth; an indisputable truth*", whereas "*the term [law] is [...] used in opposition to 'fact'*" (see entry for *law*, Id). A law is "*[t]hat which must be obeyed and followed by citizens, subject to sanctions or legal consequences*", *Id*. Likewise, [Hans Kelsen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Kelsen) defines *law* as "*the social technique which consists in bringing about the **desired** social conduct of men through the threat of a measure of coercion which is to be applied in case of contrary conduct*" (emphasis added). An axiom does not prescribe what *ought to be* (i.e., does not describe or outline the desired conduct) or how to penalize for departing from that desired conduct.

In the legal sense, a law is intrinsically conditional with a cause-effect structure, and people have discretion to violate it (subject to the risk of penalization). By contrast, axioms are so fundamental that they do not even have that cause-effect structure. Axioms exclusively serve as [fundamental] *cause* in the rest of propositions. The absence of cause-effect structure in axioms preempts even the possibility of *contrary conduct* (apropos of Kelsen's quote). A proposition or scenario that contravenes axioms would simply be discarded as *non-sequitur*.

Comment: Even physical laws such as those named after Newton, Boyle, and the like, are not axioms in the classical sense. They are neither self-evident nor indisputable, and have been revised at various times. The technical meaning of "axiom" can only be applied to the mathematical bases of a deductive system. In a less formal sense, anything thought of as a fundamental truth may be referred to as an "axiom" . The question, however, seems to use the word more to mean "tautology", but the laws of a legal system are not tautologies either.

Comment: @DavidSiegel "*They are neither self-evident nor indisputable, and have been revised at various times*". Also axioms in mathematics have undergone revisions and some of them are abstract enough to be considered *not self-evident*. But my point is that they serve as axioms insofar as the rest of the theory is premised on them and, unlike rules in a legal system, they are neither inherently conditional nor susceptible of being violated. The OP's examples in the form of *hypothesis and ontological consequence* make me doubt that he intended a connotation of tautology.

Comment: Not all mathematical axioms are conditional in form. Some serve as definitions. In any case they are different from the fundamental laws  of a physical system, and quite different from the things described in the question. I have studied meta mathematics and mathematical logic at some depth. Classical math assumed axioms to be unchangeable, modern math considers them as defining assumptions for a given mathematical system; to change axioms is to change the system.

Comment: @DavidSiegel "*Not all mathematical axioms are conditional in form*". I'm saying more than that. I'm saying that no axiom is conditional. "*Some serve as definitions*". That is a misunderstanding of what axioms are. Axioms assert something; definitions don't.

Comment: Item 1 of the famous Peano axioms is "0 is a natural number." See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Formulation I would call that a definition. Many other axiom sets include definitions as well as assertions about the entities so defined.However i fear we are getting rather far from the question asked and answered here.